# Smooth focus ramp on AVCaptureDevice

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

I am using AVCaptureDevice setFocusModeLocked to implement a focus ramp from point A to point B. The way I do it is I define delta to be something like 0.03 and then repeatedly call the API to set lensPosition.

```
   device.setFocusModeLocked(lensPosition: pointA, completionHandler: {[weak self] (time) in
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now(), execute: { [weak self] in

                if pointA == pointB {
                    device.unlockForConfiguration()
                    return
                }

                var beginPoint = fmax(currentLensPosition + delta),Float(0))
                let endPoint = fmin(pointB, Float(1.0))


                self?.focusRampRecursive( beginPoint,
                                          pointB:endPoint,
                                          delta: delta,
                                          device: device)
            })
        })
```

The problem is ramp is not smooth. There are jumps visible when the ramp happens. How can I make it smooth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a few ways.

(1) reduce the time interval to call the function repeatedly. Only slow calling will create visual noticeable effect, if it is fast enough, human cant notice e.g your light is flashing at 50hz and you think it is constantly on

(2)reduce the delta to smaller value. so that even if the time bettwen them is big, but change is very little each time. so eye also cant notice

(3) use other nonlinear mapping function like exp or log function. Instead of calling linear added ramp. other exp or log might be better as A to B is typically not linearly mapped. at the visual not very sensitive region, move faster, at the visual sensitive region, move slower. Emm  how should i describe this. The closest i can think of for illustration is stereo vision. at closer range, you actually have more discrete level to represent. and at far range, there is a lesser discrete level of representation. same apples for the focus.

the ezist way for you to experience this, is to run v4l2ucp with chesse in ubuntu.  drag the focus from one side to another. you will notice at close range it changes a lot, at the middle to far, the change is very minimal

Comment: Thanks for the response. While I tried the obvious trick of reducing time interval, it doesn't work, there are still jerks in the ramp. Primary problem is the time lens takes to go from value A to value B is not known. Suggestion 3 sounds interesting, I will try and get back to you.

Comment: Also how do I determine visually sensitive region?

Comment: For example, you can use mean/top N  corner Eigen response as a measurement.   For your previous fix interval method, capture the same corner at preset focus levels. That gives measurement(N1,N2,N3,N4....). By find the abs difference between adjcent measurement, you know how big the response changes with the given interval ( |N1-N2|,|N2-N3|.|N3-N4|......) The bigger the differential value it is , the more senstive the changes at this interval is.

Comment: To make the change gradual/ less visible to the eye, the difference between your adjacent measurement should be smaller than a value.  Hope this explains this idea clearly. if you still have doubt, you can find me in linkedlin for live chat

Comment: Is this your linkedin ID -- https://www.linkedin.com/in/shenghai-yuan-0613/?originalSubdomain=sg